# Why is cross validation used in decision tree classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, cross-validation, nearest-neighbor

I trying to learn about decision trees (and other models) and I came across cross validation, now I first thought that cross validation was used to determine the optimal parameters for the model. For example the optimal max_tree_depth in decision tree classification or the optimal number_of_neighbors in k_nearest_neighbor classification. But as I am looking at some examples I think this might be wrong.

Is this wrong?

Comment: Cross validation is used for both a) model tuning and b) model assessment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cross-validation is used to determine the accuracy of your model in a more accurate way for example in a n-fold cross validation you divide you data into n partitions and use n-1 parts as train set and 1 part as test set and repeat this for all partitions  each partition gets to be test set once) then you average results to get a better estimation of your model's accuracy

Comment: Ah I see, so it has nothing to do with finding the best parameters for your model?

Comment: @azeaze Not directly.

Comment: @NaWeeD please be careful and avoid sounding *authoritative*, especially when addressing new users (OP is evidently one); "not directly" as a reply is not enough, since CV is indeed used as a component in the model tuning process